# Object to string ValueConverter not getting invoked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have defined a Value Converter in my PCL like this:

```
class EmployeeToStringValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<Employee, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(Employee value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And I'm using it in an Android .axml layout like this:

```
local:MvxBind="Text EmployeeToString(SearchResult)"
```

(`SearchResult` is defined in the ViewModel as a public `Employee` property)

But it is not working (meaning: if I put a breakpoint in the Converter call, it is never executed).

However, I've also defined the following converter:

```
public class NegateBoolValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, bool>
{
    protected override bool Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like so:

```
local:MvxBind="Enabled NegateBool(IsLoggedIn)"
```

(`IsLoggedIn` is a `bool` public property in the ViewModel)

And this works perfectly.. Any idea so as to what may be going on with the first one that's not working?

Comment: Is there a reason `EmployeeToStringValueConverter` isn't public?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing a `public` access modifier on your converter

Changing

```
class EmployeeToStringValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<Employee, string>
```

to

```
public class EmployeeToStringValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<Employee, string>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Indeed, that was it. I wish MvvmCross would throw an error or something in scenarios like these instead of just failing silently..